# MySQL searching: bit vs char speed

Tags: mysql, database

In MySQL, is it faster to search by bit than char?

I need to select by using SELECT * from table where bit in (b"1", b"0")

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What would the corresponding "char" logic look like?  What are sample values and the results you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, What would be the benefit of using bits instead of int? For example, in order to store int: 1024, I can either use smallint or bit. What would be faster to search? int or bit?

Comment: Such optimizations are almost never needed when using relational databases.  The big picture is usually more important.  I/O is typically the dominating issue when working with large amounts of data.